# How do I remove 404 error from Django app?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a web app using Django framework. I followed the tutorial and did everything as per the tutorial.

DJANGO_PROJECT:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dellserver/', include('dellserver.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dellserver'
]
```

dellserver\urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dellserver/$', views.index, name="index")
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Why I a getting the **

> Page not found (404)

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

You did the mistake in project's url (folder which include settings.py file)

---

from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include

from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [

```
url(r'^/', include('dellserver.urls')), # this line you did the Mistake
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Answer (score 2):

in main urls remove dellserver as shown below.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('dellserver.urls')),
]
```

so that you can call your url ../dellserver/, otherwise you have to call it ../dellserver/dellserver twice.

Comment: on both urls you added dellserver, you can skip any of them